# Como conectar um banco MySql com QT em uma rede local?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, c++, servidor, qt

Olá, no momento sou noob em manipulação de servidores com bancos de dados. Estou utlizando o Qt Creator 5.3 para desenvolver o meu projeto, e decidi incorparar um banco Mysql 5.7 a ele. Estou tentando estabelecer uma conexão simples entre a minha aplicação e o banco MySql, porém sempre me deparo com a seguinte mensagem de erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Procurei em alguns foruns problemas similares, e na maioria dos casos conseguiram resolver o problema copiando o arquivo libmysql.dll da pasta C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\lib para a pasta do executável do meu projeto C:\Users\Syn\Desktop\build-Banco_MySql-Desktop_Qt_5_3_MinGW_32bit-Debug\debug. Porém mesmo seguindo este passo, e adicionando o caminho lib da dll para as variáveis de ambiente, o problema persiste. Como não mexi pesado com banco de dados e este tipo de conexão antes, nao tenho idéia do q possa ser. 
Eis abaixo o código de teste que estou utilizando:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QtSql>
#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

QSqlDatabase db;
db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
db.setHostName("localhost");
db.setPort(3306);
db.setDatabaseName("log_user");
db.setUserName("root");

if(db.open()){
    qDebug() << "Conexão foi aberta com sucesso!";
}
else{
    qDebug() << db.lastError().text();
    qApp->quit();
}

QSqlQuery qery("select * from log_user");

if(qery.exec()){

    while(qery.next())
        qDebug() << qery.value(0).toString() << "|" << qery.value(1).toString();

}
else{
    qDebug() << "Erro Fatal: " << qery.lastError().text();

}

return a.exec();
}
```

No código estou tentando acessar a tabela do banco e exibir seu conteúdo no console, mas sempre me deparo com a mesma mensagem de erro. Alguém saberia algum outro passo que posso ter deixado escapar ou alguma solução? Desde já, Agradeço a colaboração.

Obs: inclui a linha Qt += sql em .pro no meu projeto, mas parece q o problema nao é ali.

Comment: Segundo a documentação do [`QSqlQuery`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsqlquery.html#QSqlQuery-2), é necessário indicar o *db*, algo assim: `QSqlQuery qery("select * from log_user", db)`. Veja se dá certo desse modo.

Comment: Voce precisa mesmo usar o mysql, voce poderia usar o sqlite, mais facil de conectar, mais facil em varios outros aspectos, o contra é, se no seu projeto tenha sido previsto o uso de sqlprocedures, dai so com outro db msmo.

Comment: @zekk grato pela resposta mas ainda nao funcionou :/, aponta o mesmo erro "unable to connect".

Comment: Ah @Armando Marques Sobrinho , pretendo utilizar o banco com uma aplicação web posteriormente, por isso optei pelo mysql, li em alguns lugares q o Sqlite parece ter uma limitação ao ser utilizado remotamente :/

Comment: Cara, vou te falar, eu particularmente acredito que essa limitação é a falta que o sqlite tem pela dificuldade de implementar "storedprocedures" que no mysql é bem servido, mas eu tenho esse site: www.irvb.org.br, ele usa um banco de dados sqlite remoto e todos os meus aplicativos usam o sqlite normalmente

Comment: embora eu mesmo já tenha começado a pender para o lado dos dbs "nosql", tipo xml, mongodb, etc, com a tendencia "websapps" eles são uma "mão na roda"

Comment: Interessante. Darei uma estudada no sqlite, para ver se a minha aplicação se comunica melhor. Obrigado, pela resposta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, após quebrar a cabeça com algumas pesquisas descobri de onde vem o problema, mas nao necessariamente a solução completa. Eu estava usando o Mysql 5.7 da oracle. Resolvi testar a conexão com o mysql integrado do Xampp e conectou normalmente. A principio axei que poderia ser problema de compatibilidade, mas ambos meu Qt creator e Mysql sao de 32 bits. Em todo caso a solução para o meu problema será mudar para outro editor de mysql. Agradeço a resposta de todos. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Yuri,

Notei que na abertura do seu driver de conexão com o MySQL você especifica o mesmo DatabaseName (nome da base de dados) que a tabela que você tenta efetuar o SELECT mais a frente (log_user). Acredito que o problema seja esse, a menos que você possua um banco de dados chamado "log_user" também (o que não faz muito sentido, um bd só pra log de usuários).

Verifique por favor qual o nome correto do seu banco de dados e efetue esta alteração.

Lembrando que o comentário do zekk é muito importante, pois esta é a forma correta de efetuar uma consulta específica em um banco através de QSqlQuery.

Espero ter conseguido ajudar.

Comment: Ajudou sim, obrigado pela resposta. O nome do banco está correto, é 'log_user' o que acontece é que estou testando todos os tipos de transações com o banco primeiro, para depois efetuar a integraçao para a minha aplicação. Por isso criei esse banco 'log_user' para os testes.

Comment: O seu problema foi resolvido ou eu posso te ajudar em algo mais? Lembrei agora de um detalhe: O MySQL é case-sensitive para tabelas e colunas, portanto verifique se o nome da tabela está escrito exatamente como foi declarado no banco de dados.